# Circular dependency expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

sorry in advance to start another one of those circular dependency threads but I tried almost everything and maybe a fresh pair of eyes can help.
How do I get this * compiled?

CARD.H

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <irrKlang.h>
#include "Database.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace irrklang;

class Card: public Database{  // problem expected class-name before '{' token
 public:
```

DATABASE.H

```
#ifndef __DATABASE_H__
#define __DATABASE_H__

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
#include <irrKlang.h>
#include <wx/file.h>

#include "Card.h"   // even though i include card.h

using namespace std;
using namespace irrklang;

class Card;  // if i take this out, I get: 'Card' was not declared in this scope|

class Database
{
public:
vector<Card> queryC(wstring query);
```

Comment: `Card` inherits `Database`? Doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: This apperas to be a syntax error, as missing simicolon or missing parenthesis, so a code snippet that shows reprduceable code would be nice....

Answer (score 0):

Two rules to help prevent circular dependencies:
1.) If you don't need the implementation of a class, declare it by forward reference only.
2.) If you need the implementation, include the header file as late as possible.

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include "Database.h"

class Card : public Database {
    public:
            int card;
};

#endif // #ifndef CARD_H
```

Database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Card;

class Database {
    public:
            std::vector<Card> queryC(std::string query);
};

#endif // #ifndef DATABASE_H
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"

Card card;
```

Database.cpp

```
#include "Database.h"

Database database;
```

.

```
$ g++ -c Card.cpp -o Card.o
$ g++ -c Database.cpp -o Database.o
$ ls -l Card.o Database.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 959 19. Sep 09:13 Card.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 967 19. Sep 09:13 Database.o
```